# Excel Add-in Manifest: Where To Specify Minimum Required API

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-store

According to Microsoft's Office add-in documentation. the [`Requirements` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/manifest/requirements?view=office-js) in the manifest specifies "... the minimum set of JavaScript API for Office requirements that your Office Add-in needs to activate."

I can't figure out the correct place to put that element. The above-linked documentation says `Requirements` is a child of `OfficeApp`, but the Seller Dashboard and the manifest validator both say that is incorrect:

> Details: The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid
>   child element 'Requirements' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. List of
>   possible elements expected: any element in namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'.

All the docs I've read, SO questions, etc., only include snippets like:

```xml
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set name="WordApi" />
        <Set name="ExcelApi" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

But those snippets do not say under what parent to use `<Requirements>`.

Where does `Requirements` go in an Office add-in manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<Requirements>` element comes after `<Hosts>` and before `<DefaultSettings>`.

I got this by noting that:

- `<Hosts>` is the last element in the sequence of `<OfficeApp>` children ([schema link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/overview/schemas/taskpane/OfficeAppManifestV1_1.xsd#L891))
- `<Requirements> is the first element in a subsequently-defined extension to`` ([schema link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/overview/schemas/taskpane/OfficeAppManifestV1_1.xsd#L985))
- XML schema `<extension>` elements always append to the base element being extended (see, e.g., [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18852394/1780295))

I tested this by putting `<Requirements>` in various places in the file. Putting `<Requirements>` after `<Hosts>` and before `<DefaultSettings>` was the only placement that worked. (Putting `<Requirements>` as the first child did not work.)

*Thanks to user Rick Kirkham, whose now-deleted answer pointed me to the schema definition.*

Comment: I've deleted my answer. Thanks.